# Firebase Firestore - Create dynamic compound index for queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a chat system where, for sending a message, I previosly check that the sender and receiver is in the room, using a query. In a first instance, I thought to use a field "members" which was an array containing two strings (the users ids). But, the problem I had was that I would have to use two array-contains in that query

```
chatsRef
    .where("members", "array-contains", fromId)
    .where("members", "array-contains", toId)
    ...
```

Something which is not valid, as the docs says:

> you can include at most one array-contains or array-contains-any
> clause in a compound query.

So, instead of using an array, I have used a map where the key is the user's id, and the value a true boolean.

```
members = {
    "832384798238912789": true,
    "90392p2010219021ud": true,
}
```

Then I query like:

```
chatsRef
    .where(`members.${fromId}`, "==", true)
    .where(`members${toId}`, "==", true)
    ...
```

Now, the problem I am having is that I need to get all the chats of an specific user, in order of the last message date.

For this, I am querying like this:

```
const query = firebase
  .collection("chats")
  .where(`members.${firebase.getCurrentUser().uid}`, "==", true)
  .orderBy("lastMessage.date")
  .startAfter(startAfter);
```

Something which throws me a link to create a compound index which looks like this:

```
members.832384798238912789 Asc lastMessage.date Asc
```

How can I generalize this compound index for all users? I mean, something like:

```
members.key Asc lastMessage.date Asc
```

Is this possible? If not, any workaround to solve this problem?

### What I have thought to do (looking for something better, if possible):

1. Add an extra field (apart from the "members" map), "membersArray", which will allow me to query like

   ```
   .where("membersArray", "array-contains", userId)
   .orderBy("lastMessage.date")
   ```

Solves the problem but messes up the database modeling

2. Add the chat id to a subcollection for each user (unnecesary writes), so I only have to query that collection with a simple index, ignoring the

   ```
   .where(`members.${firebase.getCurrentUser().uid}`, "==", true)
   ```

Comment: The following section of the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_cli) gives a hint that you could automate the index creation with the Firebase CLI. Notice that depending on the amount of data you have this operation (index creation) might take some time. Also always be careful of hitting any of the [index limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#indexing_limits).

Comment: Regarding the approaches you propose I believe the first one will be a better choice (as without getting further inputs from your data model I don't understand why your model has a fromId and toId within a chat room).

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem, I have the same problem