# Firestore: How to query a map of roles inside a subcollection of documents?

Tags: firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, user-roles

I have the following subcollection structure:

**/projects/{projectId}/documents/{documentId}**

Where each document has an `access` map used for checking security rules for each document:

```json
{
  title: "A Great Story",
  content: "Once upon a time ...",
  access: {
    alice: true,
    bob: false,
    david: true,
    jane: false
    // ...
  }
}
```

How the security rules are set:

```
match /{path=**}/documents/{documentId} {
      allow list, get: if resource.data.access[request.auth.uid] == true;
}
```

When I want to query all documents alice can access across all projects:

```js
db.collectionGroup("documents").where(`access.${uid}`, "==", true);
```

I get an error telling me that I need to create a collection group index for `access.alice`, `access.david`, etc.

How can I overcome this indexing issue with collection group queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick overview of indexes, there are two types - a composite index (used for connecting multiple fields together) or a single-field index. By default, single-field indexes are automatically created for each field of a document for ordinary collection queries and disabled for collection group queries. If a field's value is an array, the values of that array will be added to an *Array Contains* index. If a field's value is primitive (string, number, Timestamp, etc), the document will be added to the *Ascending* and *Descending* indexes for that field.

To enable querying of the `access` field for a collection group query, you must create the index. While you could click the link in the error message you get when making the query, this would only add an index for the user you were querying (e.g. `access.alice`, `access.bob`, and so on). Instead, you should use the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/indexes/single-field/manage) to tell Cloud Firestore to create the index for `access` (which will create indexes for each of its children). Once you've got the console open, use the "Add Exemption" button (consider this use of "exemption" to mean "override default settings") to define a new indexing rule:

In the first dialog, use these settings:

```
Collection ID:      "documents"
Field Path:         "access"

Collection:         Checked ✔
Collection group:   Checked ✔
```

In the second dialog, use these settings:

|  | Collection Scope | Collection Group Scope |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ascending | *Enabled* | *Enabled* |
| Descending | *Enabled* | *Enabled* |
| Array Contains | *Enabled* | *Enabled* |

---

In your security rules, you should also check if the target user is in the `access` map before doing the equality. While accessing a missing property throws a "Property is undefined on object." error which denies access, this will become a problem if you later combine statements together with `||`.

To fix this, you can either use:

```
match /{path=**}/documents/{documentId} {
  allow list, get: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.access
                   && resource.data.access[request.auth.uid] == true;
}
```

or provide a fallback value when the desired key is not found:

```
match /{path=**}/documents/{documentId} {
  allow list, get: if resource.data.access.get(request.auth.uid, false) == true;
}
```

As an example of the rules breaking, let's say you wanted a "staff" user to be able to read a document, even if they aren't in that document's `access` map.

These rules would always error-out and fail (if the staff member's user ID wasn't in the `access` map):

```
match /{path=**}/documents/{documentId} {
  allow list, get: if resource.data.access[request.auth.uid] == true
                   || get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.get("staff", false) == true;
}
```

whereas, these rules would work:

```
match /{path=**}/documents/{documentId} {
  allow list, get: if resource.data.access.get(request.auth.uid, false) == true
                   || get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.get("staff", false) == true;
}
```

---

As a side note, unless you need to query for documents where a user does not have access to it, it is simpler to simply omit that user from the access map.

```json
{
  title: "A Great Story",
  content: "Once upon a time ...",
  access: {
    alice: true,
    david: true,
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! 
One follow up question is, what if I add an `orderBy("createdDate")` to the query above? Will this index work for compound queries?

Comment: Noted:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980243/in-firestore-how-can-you-do-a-compound-query-involving-a-key-in-a-map-without-c?rq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767799/firebase-firestore-create-dynamic-compound-index-for-queries
Apparently I would have to denomalize the access map into an array to be able to use the `orderBy()`

Comment: @Hernantz Adding the exception just tells Firestore to build the single-field indexes under `access`. Using a different field for `orderBy`, as you identified, needs a composite index (merges two or more single-field indexes together). As you've also noticed, in order to build only a single composite index without needing one for each field under `access`, you could use of an array field. So add an array called `accessMembers` of the user IDs/usernames under `access`. With this structure, you can use `access` to even assign roles for a given post (editor, contributor, etc).

Answer (score 2):

As noted on https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#collection-group-query "Before using a collection group query, you must create an index that supports your collection group query. You can create an index through an error message, the console, or the Firebase CLI."

In this case you'll want to enable CollectionGroup queries on the access map (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing#add_a_single-field_index_exemption)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create an index for it as mentioned by @Jim.
If you don't want to get much into it, you can just catch the error and it'll have a direct link to to create one as shown below:
[image]

```
db.collectionGroup("documents").where(`access.${uid}`, "==", true).get().then((snap) => {
  //
}).catch((e) => console.log(e))
```

Other ways as mentioned in the documentation include:

> Before using a collection group query, you must create an index that
> supports your collection group query. You can create an index through
> an error message, the console, or the Firebase CLI.